# Regular dump from one mysql database to another with cron

Tags: mysql

I have wirtten this line in /etc/crontab file to take daily dump from one database to another every night at 3, but doesn't wrok neither does it give any error messages.

```
0 3 * * * mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --opt activeDB | mysql -uroot -ppassword -h test.example.com passiveDB
```

Any idea what is wrong here? Do I need to define for example a ssh connection for the server? If that is the problem, I guess it should give some message like connection to the given server is not allowed, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write your command to a shell script, and call that script from the crontab. Some versions of cron dont read multi-part commands very well.
2. You should debug your command first, before setting it up in a cron.

You need to make sure that `mysqld` is listening on the public interface at `test.example.com` (it isn't by default). You need to make sure you have the correct `GRANT` permissions set up on the remote database, you need to grant permissions to 'user'@'%' (bad idea) or 'user'@'your-active-server-ip' (better idea).

Comment: You are right. After debugging, I get "active server is not allowed to connect to passive server". So I got some more stuff to do yet. Thanks.

Comment: Problem solved. had to allow access to mysql server port from the active server and also grant permissions to it on test.example.com. Thanks again lynks.

Comment: np, it had to be one of those things.